# C# - Integration with Siscan (web service)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, integration

All ok, people?

I need consume some methods of a webservice available at:
http://aplicacao-homologacao.saude.gov.br/ws-siscan/SiscanWS?wsdl 
I'm doing as follows (do not know if it's the right way):

```
    protected static void LiberarLaudo()
    {
        try
        {                
            var oServicoSISCAN = new SiscanWSClient();
            var oliberarLaudo = new liberarLaudo();

            oliberarLaudo.identificacao = new identificacao();
            oliberarLaudo.laudo = new liberarLaudoXSD();

            oliberarLaudo.identificacao.email = "anything";
            oliberarLaudo.identificacao.senha = "anything";
            oliberarLaudo.identificacao.cnesPrestador = "anything";
            oliberarLaudo.identificacao.cnesUnidadeSaude = "anything";

            oliberarLaudo.laudo.cartaoSUSPaciente = "anything";
            oliberarLaudo.laudo.cpfResponsavelLaudo = "anything";
            oliberarLaudo.laudo.dataColeta = "anything";
            oliberarLaudo.laudo.tipoExame = "anything";
            oliberarLaudo.laudo.numeroProtocoloDaRequisicao = "anything";
            oliberarLaudo.laudo.tipoLateralidade = "anything";

            oliberarLaudo.identificacao.perfilUsuario = "anything";

            //Here happens the exception...
            var retorno = oServicoSISCAN.liberarLaudo(oliberarLaudo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

See here the thrown exception (with the Translate of "Additional Information"). click to **zoom**

[image]

Below is the error server stack trace:

> Server stack trace: em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.SerializeBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, Object[] parameters, Object returnValue, Boolean isRequest)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message, Boolean shouldRecycleBuffer)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      em Siscan.Program.LiberarLaudo() na d:\Projetos\Ciprodam\Antonio-Testes\Siscan\Siscan\Program.cs:linha 216
>      em Siscan.Program.Main(String[] args) na d:\Projetos\Ciprodam\Antonio-Testes\Siscan\Siscan\Program.cs:linha 20
>      em System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>      em System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>      em Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>      em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>      em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Please can anyone help me to make this web service work?
Thanks so much for attention!

Comment: Can someone translate the "Additional Information" in the exception screenshot above?

Comment: Hi Micky, how are you? Sorry, I translated the "Additional Information" in the exception screenshot. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hmm says it can't convert type `string[]`.  Is it possible you could post the c# code definition of `liberarLaudoRequest`?  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to C # code of this method, because it comes from the web service...
Please, you could create a little project, add a References Service for http://aplicacao-homologacao.saude.gov.br/ws-siscan/SiscanWS?wsdl and try to use as I posted? Possibly this way get better for you to understand... Thanks so much!